# QGIS 2 Installation on MAC OSX - couldn't load plugin 'processing'

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-processing, mac, osx

New installation of QGIS running on Macbook Pro OSX 10.8.4 - this comes up on start-up. I urgently need this fixed!!! I have a project due in 10 days that I desperately need QGIS for.

```
Couldn't load plugin 'processing' from ['/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python', '/Users/caitlinsommer/.qgis2/python', '/Users/caitlinsommer/.qgis2/python/plugins', '/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins', '/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/B/Python/2.7', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-override', '/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.10/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins/fTools/tools']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 182, in loadPlugin
    __import__(packageName)
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 453, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/__init__.py", line 20, in 
    from processing.tools.general import runalg, runandload, alghelp, alglist, algoptions, load, extent, getobject
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 453, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/tools/general.py", line 29, in 
    from processing.core.Processing import Processing
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 453, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/core/Processing.py", line 52, in 
    from processing.admintools.AdminToolsAlgorithmProvider import AdminToolsAlgorithmProvider
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 453, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/admintools/AdminToolsAlgorithmProvider.py", line 19, in 
    from processing.admintools.PostGISExecuteSQL import PostGISExecuteSQL
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 453, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/admintools/PostGISExecuteSQL.py", line 32, in 
    from processing.admintools import postgis_utils
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 453, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/admintools/postgis_utils.py", line 39, in 
    import psycopg2
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 453, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named psycopg2

Python version:
2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)]


QGIS version:
2.0.1-Dufour Dufour, f738351

Python path: ['/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python', '/Users/caitlinsommer/.qgis2/python', '/Users/caitlinsommer/.qgis2/python/plugins', '/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins', '/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/B/Python/2.7', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-override', '/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.10/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins/fTools/tools']
```

Answer (score 2):

> ImportError: No module named psycopg2

Seems that you need to install 'psycopg2' package that lets Python to interact with PostgreSQL. I suppose you will be able to install it via your package manager. Or you may get it from [here](http://initd.org/psycopg/).